# GoDaddy want to know MX records to route my email

Tags: email

I have a web site at godaddy and want to send all my email to force.com without setting up email boxes on godaddy. Here is what GoDaddy is asking:

"You will need to ask your email company for their MX Records (Mail Exchange Records). Once you have those you can call us and we can show you where to put them into your domain name."

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce.com isn't going to directly handle your mail for you. Email services needs specific addresses in order to work, and since they're just going to point the DNS at the MX you specify, that mail won't be delivered; any such mail outside of the domains they support, such as salesforce.com and force.com, will be bounced or discarded.

Instead, you need *someone* to handle your email accounts, so you can at least set up forwarding rules to redirect to the appropriate Force.com email handler that you intend to use. I'd recommend GoDaddy, since you already have them, but you could just as easily set up your own Exchange server on a local domain controller, or find a pure email-hosting company that has forwarding rules you can use.